# Prove that $(R,+,\cdot)$ is a ring with unity where $(R,\cdot)$ is a monoid

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $(R,+)$ be a group and $(R,\cdot)$ be a monoid and the distributive laws $a\cdot(a+b)=a\cdot b+a\cdot c$, and $(b+c)\cdot a=b\cdot a+c\cdot a$ hold in $R$. Prove that $(R,+,\cdot)$  is a ring with unity.

Comment: What you have stated here is the definition of ring with unity. There is nothing to prove.

Comment: @Mohan, no, it's not, since $+$ is not assumed to be commutative. Please see my answer.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti It (not the fact, but the need to prove) may depend on what definition o f ring the OP is using. E.g. One might *define* a ring as group $(R,+)$ and monoid $(R,\cdot)$ with distributive laws and then prove as *theorem* that the group $(R,+)$ is abelian.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen, so your guess is that OP is indeed asking the question *"Suppose $R$ is a ring, prove it is a ring"*. Fair enough, My own guess is that since OP has explicitly talked of a *ring with unity* (as opposed, I guess to just plain ring), he has a different definition in mind. But I am definitely biased, because I am thinking of the definition I tend to use.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti I thought $(R,+)$ represents a commutative group.+ operation is generally used for abelian groups.

Comment: @Mohan, of course this is a commonly used convention, but for instance in the theory of near-rings $+$ is used for not necessarily commutative operations: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearring

Answer (score 5):

The point is, $+$ is not assumed to be commutative, so to prove that $R$ with these operations is a ring, you have to show that commutativity holds for addition.

This follows from the following chain of equalities, for $a, b \in R$,
$$
a + b + a + b
=
(a + b) (1 + 1)
=
a (1 + 1) + b (1 + 1)
=
a + a + b + b,
$$
where I have used *both distributive laws*. Now add $-a$ on the left and $-b$ on the right to show $b + a = a + b$.

**PS** Perhaps it should be remarked that if $(R, \cdot)$ is only assumed to be a semigroup, so no unity, then you cannot prove you get a ring. In fact, given any noncommutative group $(R, +, 0)$, you could define on it the trivial multiplication $ab = 0$ for all $a, b \in R$.